# Laravel 5.2 + Create Validation for Form

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have one form. Which has below fields

1. text field
2. Add More
3. Submit button.

When clicked on **Add More** button, It will add new **text field** in the form.

I want to apply require field validation on all text fields using Laravel.

Please Let me know how this is possible.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What is the error message? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In 5.1 you can place something akin to the following in a FormRequest class...

```
foreach ($this->request->get('text-field-name') as $key => $val)
{
    $rules['text-field-name.' . $key] = 'required';
}
```

In 5.2 you have a further choice in that Laravel includes built-in functionality for validating arrays: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays)